# workflow runtime ownership expired

Tags: workflow-foundation

I am facing a strange problem in windows workflow foundation. I have created a State Machine Workflow, and it worked very fine in one build, but due to some requirements I altered the workflow, built and re-installed the application. Now when I am trying to access workflow instances that I created in a previous build, it gives me a `WorkflowOwnershipException`:

> This workflow is not owned by the WorkflowRuntime. The WorkflowRuntime's ownership has expired, or another WorkflowRuntime owns the workflow.

Is there a workaround or way to fix the root cause of this problem?

Comment: I didn't think you were supposed to use the title of the question as the tags...

Answer (score 0):

How long is the lock time for the persistence service? I'm assuming you're using the built in SqlWorkflowPersistenceService.

Maybe this infomation helps you:

http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,9c484cc4-ddd7-4dfd-b8e3-d5517fe9b0a2.aspx